# How to run my selenium runnable jar in a different machine without driver files

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to export my project as a *runnable jar* and run it without driver.exe files being present. I tried incorporating them with below code to make it independent but still unable to run the jar file without driver files being presenting in the same folder.

**code:**

```
String currentDir=System.getProperty("user.dir");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", currentDir+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager#webdrivermanager-as-java-dependency) for this purpose:

You can download the dependency by Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:3.6.1")
}
```

Then on the code, you just need to setup the driver and create the driver objects:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You can find details about driver version [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager#driver-versions).

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm!!! :)

Comment: Most welcome. Could you mark the answer as accepted?